# Prevent AngularJS from compiling contents of element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-compile

Is there a way to tell Angular to not compile contents of certain elements?

Use case:

Angular CMS contains `textarea` elements that have *CKEditor* attached. The CKEditor is using the *divarea* plugin instead of the default *iframe* plugin. The textareas contain HTML templates. These templates are exported on demand and fed to a Angular webapp.

The templates are simple enough: plain text, ordered lists, the occasional predefined class attribute applied on the plain text; but the plain text can contain placeholders for the Angular webapp to interpolate. I do not want to let the Angular in the CMS interpolate these at all.

Currently my problem is that the Angular in the CMS interpolates these placeholders and, since they don't refer to anything, removes them. I would rather not just change the delimiters to '{[', ']}', as while this might fix this in the short term, the chance of directive and text copy collision increases as the project goes on, and I'd like to avoid it.

Is there any directive or other way to tell Angular to keep away from the content of specially marked elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`ng-non-bindable` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) on the element:

> The ngNonBindable directive tells Angular not to compile or bind the
>   contents of the current DOM element. This is useful if the element
>   contains what appears to be Angular directives and bindings but which
>   should be ignored by Angular.

Or use your own directive with `terminal: true` property to match the layout better, because it is [the only thing that `ng-non-bindable` directive does](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.3/src/ng/directive/ngNonBindable.js#L35).